# How to modify ros-launch file?

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm using ROS kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04.

I've ever modified existing ROS-launch files some times, but all I did was to change the parameter's name or values.

This time I want to add another node into the launch file, and I'm pretty wondering above whether I have to modify CMakelist.txt or any other files to make sure I'll use another node.

Is it OK if I add some lines into the launch file without any modification on the files kinds of CMakelist.txt?

And also, can I include a node which is in another workspace?
I mean,

```
<include file="$(find A DIRECTORY FROM ANOTHER WORKSPACE)/THE_LAUNCHFILE.launch" >
```

is the above OK?

Thanks in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339881/how-to-modify-ros-launch-file?/) by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2019-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a little tutorial [here](http://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/ros/Launch%20Files.html) explainning how to write a launch file.

> Is it OK if I add some lines into the launch file without any modification on the files kinds of CMakelist.txt?

Don't hesitate to try and see what happen ;) The answer is yes, `CMakeLists.txt` files are used to build your packages while launch file will simply look for the executables created after the building.

> And also, can I include a node which is in another workspace?

Just to be clear : you include launch files but not nodes.

You can do that, it's called [workspace chaining](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying#Chaining_catkin_workspaces).

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1